# Why will my PL/SQL procedure not compile when there are line breaks?

Tags: oracle, plsql, toad

Below is some logic from a stored procedure that I am trying to compile.  When there are no line breaks, it compiles just fine.  But, when I break it up it won't compile.  Why is that?

The code when it works right:

```
DECLARE
curr_fy varchar2(4);
last_fy varchar2(4);
get_month number;
BEGIN
get_month := to_number(to_char(sysdate, 'MM'));
If get_month < 6 then
curr_fy := to_char(sysdate, 'YYYY');
last_fy := to_char(sysdate, 'YYYY') - 1;
END IF;
If get_month > 5 then
curr_fy := to_char(sysdate, 'YYYY') + 1;
last_fy := to_char(sysdate, 'YYYY');
END IF;
dbms_output.put_line(curr_fy);
END;
```

The code when it doesn't work right:

```
DECLARE

curr_fy varchar2(4);
last_fy varchar2(4);
get_month number;

BEGIN

get_month := to_number(to_char(sysdate, 'MM'));

If get_month < 6 then
curr_fy := to_char(sysdate, 'YYYY');
last_fy := to_char(sysdate, 'YYYY') - 1;
END IF;

If get_month > 5 then
curr_fy := to_char(sysdate, 'YYYY') + 1;
last_fy := to_char(sysdate, 'YYYY');
END IF;

dbms_output.put_line(curr_fy);

END;
```

I am getting the following error message when I compile the second version of the code:  ORA-00900: invalid SQL statement

I am using the newest version of TOAD.

Comment: I imagine it's something to do with Toad, as both your examples compile in SQL Developer.

Comment: Compiles and runs fine in PL/SQL Developer as well. Please edit your question and include information regarding the errors you get when running this in Toad. Thanks.

Comment: Maybe TOAD behaves like SQL*Plus: an empty line terminates the statement.

Comment: You should execute with F9, not CTRL+Enter or Shift+F9. The latter two use legacy code that interprets blank lines as SQL terminators which is incorrect, technically. F9 uses a parser which accurately detects your statements. There are numerous reasons why F9 should be used over the legacy features that have been covered at length on the Toad forums.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I haven't used TOAD, but my guess is TOAD is treating each line followed by an empty line as a separate SQL statement. So in your case TOAD maybe trying to execute `DECLARE` as a SQL statement which is incorrect.

My suggestion would be to select/highlight the whole anonymous block using mouse cursor and then click on the execute button. This usually works in free tools like SQL Developer.